# Adding a second IP to Debian Server

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, ip

I was given a second IP by my server provider. I am running Debian 5.0. I thought I knew how to add the IP to the system and configure with apache, but I have not yet been able to.

The primary IP works fine and I have a few sites already running on that one.

What steps would I take to add this second IP so that I use it in apache?

Comment: You are supposed to configure a new alias for your second ip. The mandatory resources for ip management are the file /etc/network/interfaces and the ip tool from iproute package. Where are things breaking? what doesn't work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the new IP address is on the same subnet as the first, add a second virtual interface (sometimes called an "alias") to the primary network interface.  This is configured, like all network interface settings, in `/etc/network/interfaces`.  The Debian Reference manual has a section on the topic:

http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_virtual_interface

A simple example, assuming your primary network interface is `eth0` and has an ip of `192.168.1.1` and the new ip is `192.168.1.2`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.254

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Once the appropriate settings have been added to `/etc/network/interfaces`, run `ifup eth0:0` to activate the new interface.

If, however, the new ip is on a different subnet, you need to either provision the ip on a physically distinct network interface or create a VLAN interface, depending on how your ISP is prepared to hand it off to you.  That's a whole new topic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried following these instructions, but when I restart the network interfaces I receive this error:

:/etc# /etc/init.d/networking restart
Reconfiguring network interfaces...SIOCDELRT: No such process
if-up.d/mountnfs[eth0]: waiting for interface eth0:0 before doing NFS mounts (warning).
done.

The subnet is the same for the ips, so from what I know and read this above solution should work. The virtual host that I setup are not working and I get network timeout on the domain.

Comment: The warnings sound reasonable.  The fact that it makes reference to waiting for eth0:0 is good news.  What do your network interfaces look like after restarting networking?  Specifically, what does the output of "`ifconfig -a`" look like?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface

Comment: Your debian.org link is broken. Also the [eth0:0](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) method is apparently obsolete, see the Legacy method section.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the [`iproute`](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/Net:Iproute2) package, you can put this in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.17
    netmask 255.0.0.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    up   ip addr add 10.0.0.18 dev eth0
    down ip addr del 10.0.0.18 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

Even Simpler:

Use an "addresses" line in */etc/network/interfaces*

```
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.10.0.66
        netmask 255.255.255.240
        network 10.10.0.64
        broadcast 10.10.0.79
        gateway 10.10.0.65
        addresses 10.10.0.67/28 10.10.0.67/28 10.10.0.68/28
```

You can use a space seperated list of IPs/CIDR netmasks.

This is a crippled version of my interface definition (IPs changed and only relevant part)

Comment: I can't find the `addresses` line in the manpages `interfaces` or `ifconfig`, neither does it work on Debian Lenny.

Comment: I have to down vote this, as it's not in Debian Buster's ifupdown either. https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface