# flushed IPs by mistake on UNIX how to recover from rescue

Tags: ip, debian-squeeze

I got a problem.

OS: `Linux Debian 6.0 64-Bit`

I used this command on my root-server:
`ip addr flush dev eth0`

I added some month agp multiply IP's and that in a false format.
The problem is since i used the command i directly disconnected from my SSH connection, neither I were able to reconnect.

I restarted the server and it also didnt help.

Now the server is in rescue mode and I have a connection.
How can I recover and fix my issue? I just heard that it's not possible to use `ip addr add` because it will be removed after rebooting.

My current `/etc/network/interfaces`-file include this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 212.224.126.68
        netmask 255.255.255.128
        network 212.224.126.0
        broadcast 212.224.126.127
        gateway 212.224.126.1
```

We already started the server with this config but the problem is the server seems not to start up successfully or is for us unaccessable.

Is there any chance to recover that, or do I need to reinstall my whole server? :-(

Comment: So this is not really an IP-connectivity problem but your server simply doesn't boot up at all? And this interfaces file is from the rescue-system, not from the harddrive? Try mounting the root partition from the harddrive into the rescue system. There, inspect the real interfaces file and look for logs indicating, why the system doesn't boot.

Comment: Well I think its because of the flush of my IPs, because that was the last thing I have done.
I have mounted my chroot, as you said. Is there something like a log where I could look up my issues? Sorry, I'm a newbie in that area. I never had such issues before in 3-4 years.

Comment: With respect, what you think is meaningless, because you don't know what the problem is.  It's worth noting as a datum "*the last thing I changed before the problem was X*", but unless you did a reboot immediately before that change you have no reason to conclude that that was the change that rendered the system unbootable.  Keep an open mind, gather all possible information, **then** form a hypothesis; the other way around doesn't work so well.

Comment: Have you checked the `/etc/network/interfaces` file in your mounted root filesystem that the IP address settings are correct in it? So, if your root filesystem is mounted at `/mnt`, you need to edit `/mnt/etc/network/interfaces` in the rescue system.

Answer (score 0):

As first aid, add the network configuration manually.

As an example, I assume the following paramaters:

```
Interface:       eth0
IP-address:      192.168.1.22
Network Mask:    255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Then, as user root, run:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.22/255.255.255.0 dev eth0
```

The interface is now configured. Now add a default route:

```
ip route add default 192.168.1.1
```

Now networking is reconfigured until the next reboot. To make your changes permanent, open the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and adapt the `iface eth0` section like mentioned in [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/).

Also refer to the [official documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Configuring_the_interface_manually). As of adding more IP-addresses to the same interface, refer to [this other posting](https://serverfault.com/questions/66901/adding-a-second-ip-to-debian-server).

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I think I have already that part on my file. I just updated my question with the latest info.